# Simple Blog Extension for Spree 3.0 or above

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Are there any simple blog extension for spree 3.0 or above.I want to integrate a blog in my spree store. 
I checked https://github.com/stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree but apparently its not working with spree 3.0.1.
Is there any other simple work around ?.I don't want to invest a lot of time and resources in developing a blog from scratch.

Comment: For now (early 2016) there doesn't seem to be any useful Spree extension targeting 3.0 stable version and the link for extension page on SpreeCommerce is not working. If you want to use a lot of other features which are brought to you by the extensions it is better idea to switch back to v2.3 or v2.4. But if you insist to use v3.0 stable you can always write your own and contribute to the community.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close *https://github.com/stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree* is the solution but it only works upto spree version 2.3, in order to make in compatible with later versions people forked the repo and made the desired changes for ex:

http://krazedkrish.com/blog/2015/11/03/blogging-with-spree-3-0-stable/

Installation:

```
gem 'spree_blogging_spree', github: 'krazedkrish/spree-blogging-spree', branch: '3-0-stable'

$ bundle install

$ rake railties:install:migrations

$ rake db:migrate
```

Other forked repositories to work with Spree 3.0 and above

https://github.com/kshlyk/spree-blogging-spree/tree/3-0-stable

https://github.com/JuandGirald/spree-blogging-spree/tree/spree-3-0-rc2

https://github.com/coalla/spree-blogging-spree/tree/3-0-stable

https://github.com/garpit/spree-blogging-spree/tree/3-0-stable

https://github.com/mobentec/spree-blogging-spree/tree/3-0-stable

https://github.com/b8in/spree-blogging-spree/tree/spree-3-0-rc2

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

> ... Is there any other simple work around ?.I don't want to invest a lot of time and resources in developing a blog from scratch. ...

Dont forget to check the forks, in your case, I have already forked https://github.com/stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree to https://github.com/krazedkrish/spree-blogging-spree, and added compatibility with spree 3.0 stable.

And if there is'nt a fork that is updated, you can always fork the repo and make necessary changes instead of starting from scratch.